# Needing help to solve error message after attempting to create new entry with CRUD app Spring MVC MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I am not inputting a null entry, not sure what this has to do with. I have tried changing the input types and the database properties. I am new to Java and using Spring MVC for this.

HTML File to for create "new" form:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Description: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="*{description}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Price: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="*{price}" /></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button> </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.invoicebuilder;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties.Job;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * @author jmens
 *
 */
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List<job> listJobs = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listJobs", listJobs);

        return "index";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public String showNewJobForm(Model model) {
        Job job = new Job();
        model.addAttribute("job", job);

        return "new_job";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveJob(@ModelAttribute("job") job job) {
    service.save(job);

    return "redirect:/";
    }
}`
```

This is the error code that I am having issues with, I am using MySQL for the database and am able to make it all the way to the screen where I am able to create the new job entry but after clicking save, it gives me an error as shown below:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'description' cannot be null
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector- 
java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~ 
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~ 
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) 
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) 
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~ 
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~ 
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~ 
[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3090) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3683) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:804) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.15.Final.jar:5.3.15.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:351) ~[spring-orm-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310) ~[spring-orm-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:535) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.invoicebuilder.InvoiceService.save(InvoiceService.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
at com.invoicebuilder.AppController.saveJob(AppController.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the description field is not filled

I suppose you are using Thymeleaf, so make sure to map your controller with your form like:

```
<form th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${job}" method="POST">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
   <tr>
     <td>Description: </td>
     <td><input type="text" th:field="*{description}" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> Price: </td>
     <td><input type="text" th:field="*{price}" /></td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button> </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

In your Controller change job ==> Job

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveJob(@ModelAttribute("job") job job) {
service.save(job);
return "redirect:/";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a model attribute by name like `@ModelAttribute("job")` you have to set the same name in the `<form>` element of your view. Right now you don't wrap it inside a `<form>` and just an HTML `<table>`

The following should work:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" modelAttribute="job" th:object="${job}" method="POST">
    <label>Description:</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" th:field="*{description}">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" th:field="*{price}">

  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Save">
</form>
```

The code above might not have the best look-and-feel but should technically work and you can adjust it further to look properly